# Python game design without Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.3

This topic is in response to a problem I've been having getting Pygame to be set up correctly on my computer.  I have Windows 7, Python 3.3 and "64-bit" Windows (now I know what a bit and a byte are, but I don't really understand the implications of having a "64-bit" computer)  I'm proficient in Python but know nothing about binaries, dependencies, registries or other such internal/system-level structures; not that I'm not interested, but at the moment most of what goes on is essentially "over my head".

But anyway, with that said, the problem I've been experiencing is basically that I can't install pygame.  I've been over several versions of the same question (on Stack Overflow and other places on the web), and I've attempted to install pygame countless times.  Sometimes it seems to work fine until I attempt to use it (the installation appears to have been successful but Python gives me errors when I try to use pygame), or I get something about Python 3.3 not being in my "registry" (which from what I read appears to be another OS-level/internal structure for those who understand "the base code of the universe").  They could actually develop a series of tutorials on just the installation process. :)

But all joking aside, I am at a loss here and considering just giving up on pygame.  So my question would be, is there any way to use what's already installed (Python's libraries etc.) to develop games?  If not, do you know of any alternatives that don't require the same level of experience to install?  I've Googled around but everything I've found about game design in Python leads back to pygame.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of games do you want to develop? `tkinter` will give you basic GUI, if that's what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To save yourself pain, just use 32bit python, and 32bit pygame. If you mix 32 and 64 bit, it will not run correctly. That's probably the problem you're having.

Since you have python 3.3, you would use https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads/pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.3.msi

You shouldn't have to edit the registry or your environmentvariables unless something goes wrong.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea.  I'll have to look into how to get 32-bit Python and give it a try.  Thanks. :)

Comment: Is this the 32-bit python? "•Windows x86 MSI Installer"

Comment: It technically is not, but it will run and function exactly like it is

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned previously, tkinter would offer a solution. For example, this was created in tkinter (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHxLkNryOzI)

Comment: This was done with tkinter?  I've worked with tkinter's canvas widget before but never seen anything like that; how would that work with event handling (arrow keys, mouse clicks, or however this person made his "player" object move)?

Answer (score 1):

The pygame downloads page hasn't been updated for a while and is incompatible with python 3.x. Newer versions of pygame can be downloaded [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

I'd personally use pygame as there's audio support as well but tkinter could be used.

Comment: Pygame installers from 2013-04 are at the main download https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads